# Terraform destroy Command Deleting Microsoft First-Party Azure AD Enterprise Applications

Tags: terraform, azure-active-directory

We've developed a Terraform package for registering and deploying a new Azure AD application. This application relies on various native Microsoft Azure AD enterprise applications like MS Teams, Intune, Exchange, SharePoint etc. as shown in the following code snippet:

```
resource "azuread_service_principal" "exchange" {
  application_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.Office365ExchangeOnline
  use_existing   = true
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "sharepoint" {
  application_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.Office365SharePointOnline
  use_existing   = true
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "intune" {
  application_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.InTune
  use_existing   = true
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "teams" {
  application_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.TeamsServices
  use_existing   = true
}
```

We are aware of the documented caveats associated with using use_existing flag https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/service_principal that says -

> Terraform will still attempt to delete the service principal on
> destroy, although it will not raise an error if the deletion fails (as
> it often the case for first-party Microsoft applications)

However, it appears that, after running the 'destroy' command, Terraform has deleted some first-party enterprise applications from Azure AD, such as Exchange and SharePoint.

This raises a question:

- Is Terraform unintentionally deleting Microsoft first-party enterprise applications?

Any assistance on this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

[Update] - We have noticed that there is already an open issue raised within the AzureAD provider repository for this - https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/1141

Comment: I don't think this is not a terraform specific problem, rather an Azure provider one.

Comment: Yes, we thought so too. Here are the version details for reference
hashicorp/azuread v2.45.0 and terraform v1.4.4